# Sort the inner array using LINQ

Tags: go

I have a two-layer array, the outer layer is already grouped and sorted by shopid, and I want to sort the inner layer by decreasing price without changing the order of the outer layer。

```
// Inner struct
type product struct {
    name   string
    price  int64
    shopId int64
}

// Outer struct
type oneGroup struct {
    shopId   int64
    products []*product
}

// Final Outer array
var groupOut []oneGroup
```

The input to linq should be [groupOut]

I took advantage of linq to group and sort the outer layer (Grouping and sorting outer layers in descending order according to the largest price in the group after grouping). But didn't know what to do with the inner layer.

```
products := make([]*product, 0, 20)
products = append(products, &product{name: "product66", price: 6666, shopId: 100})
products = append(products, &product{name: "product11", price: 1111, shopId: 100})
products = append(products, &product{name: "product44", price: 4444, shopId: 100})

products = append(products, &product{name: "product22", price: 2222, shopId: 200})
products = append(products, &product{name: "product77", price: 9999, shopId: 200})
products = append(products, &product{name: "product00", price: 0000, shopId: 200})

products = append(products, &product{name: "product33", price: 3333, shopId: 300})
products = append(products, &product{name: "product88", price: 8888, shopId: 300})
products = append(products, &product{name: "product55", price: 5555, shopId: 300})

products = append(products, &product{name: "product99", price: 7777, shopId: 400})

var query []linq.Group

//Grouping and sorting outer layers in descending order according to the largest price in the group after grouping
linq.From(products).GroupByT(
    func(p *product) int64 { return p.shopId },
    func(p *product) *product { return p },
).OrderByT(
    func(g linq.Group) int64 {
        //return g.Key.(int64)
        return linq.From(g.Group).Select(
            func(x interface{}) interface{} { return x.(*product).price },
        ).Max().(int64)

    },
).ToSlice(&query)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, build an ordered query of products sorted by shopId and then by price in descending order.

This allows for the inner array of each group to be sorted accordingly.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/ahmetb/go-linq/v3"
)

// Inner struct
type product struct {
    name   string
    price  int64
    shopId int64
}
func (x product) String() string { return fmt.Sprintf("<%s, [%d]> ", x.name, x.price) }

// Outer struct
type oneGroup struct {
    shopId   int64
    products []*product
}

// Final Outer array
var groupOut []oneGroup

func main() {
    products := make([]*product, 0, 20)
    products = append(products, &product{name: "product66", price: 6666, shopId: 100})
    products = append(products, &product{name: "product11", price: 1111, shopId: 100})
    products = append(products, &product{name: "product44", price: 4444, shopId: 100})

    products = append(products, &product{name: "product22", price: 2222, shopId: 200})
    products = append(products, &product{name: "product77", price: 9999, shopId: 200})
    products = append(products, &product{name: "product00", price: 0000, shopId: 200})

    products = append(products, &product{name: "product33", price: 3333, shopId: 300})
    products = append(products, &product{name: "product88", price: 8888, shopId: 300})
    products = append(products, &product{name: "product55", price: 5555, shopId: 300})

    products = append(products, &product{name: "product99", price: 7777, shopId: 400})

    var query []linq.Group
    // Sort products first by shopId and the price in descending order
    var productsByShopIdAndPrice linq.OrderedQuery = linq.From(products).OrderByT(func(p interface{}) int64  {
        return p.(*product).shopId
    }).ThenByDescending(func(p interface{}) interface{} {
        return p.(*product).price
    })
    // Grouping and sorting outer layers in descending order according to the largest price in the group after grouping
    productsByShopIdAndPrice.GroupByT(
        func(p *product) int64 { return p.shopId },
        func(p *product) *product { return p },
    ).OrderByT(
        func(g linq.Group) int64 {
            //return g.Key.(int64)
            return linq.From(g.Group).Select(
                func(x interface{}) interface{} { return x.(*product).price },
            ).Max().(int64)

        },
    ).ToSlice(&query)
    fmt.Printf("%v \n", query)
}
```